# SugarCRM - Where is a list a possible Vardefs / array attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar 6.5

I just want to know a list of possible Vardefs?

For example, I've seen these:

```
array (
'name' => 'some_dropdown',
'studio' => 'visible',
'label' => 'LBL_MY_LABEL',
'customCode' => '',
'customCodeRenderField' =>,
```

I know what `customCode` means, but what does `customCodeRenderField` do? Where can I look up all the possible elements to edit a particular field within editviewdefs and detailviewdefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find answers

- Here: [Sugar Developer Guide](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/03_Module_Framework/03_Vardefs/00_Introduction/)